# jq: mapping json objects to another format schema

Tags: json, jq

I need to transform an array of this kind of elements:

```
[
  {
    "Field1": "value1",
    "Field2": "value2"
  },
  {
    "Field1": "value3",
    "Field2": "value4"
  },
  ...
]
```

To:

```
[
    "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
            "Field1": {
                "S": "value1"
            },
            "Field2": {
                "S": "value2"
            }
        }
    },
    "PutRequest": {
        "Item": {
            "Field1": {
                "S": "value3"
            },
            "Field2": {
                "S": "value4"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
]
```

I was thinking about using `jq`, but I don't quite figure out how to get it.

**EDIT**

Up to now, I've been able to get that:

```
[.[] | {"Field1": {"S": .Field1}, "Field2": {"S": .Field2}}]
```

Is there any what to say: for each field add an like `key: {"S": .value}`?

**EDIT 2**
Using `map({PutRequest: {Item: map_values({S: .})}})` approach, it's generating me:

```
 {
    "S": {
      "Field1": "value1",
      "Field2": "value2",
    }
}
```

I need:

```
"Item": {
    "Field1": {
        "S": "value3"
    },
    "Field2": {
        "S": "value4"
    }
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your programming environment where you would like to achieve this?

Comment: It looks like that you want to convert input data to DynamoDB records. Is that true?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is.

Comment: I would suggest you to read jq tutorial : https://stedolan.github.io/jq/ 
This is pretty standard transformation.

Comment: If you still face a problem, add what you have tried so far and the community will help you to improve it.

Comment: Your expected output is invalid JSON. Arrays can't contain fields.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does not exactly match your expected output but you're probably looking for something like this:

```
map({PutRequest: {Item: map_values({S: .})}})
```

<sup>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/1zmdv4U2Yk)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, I likely miswrote something.